# Regex for url without containing (http|https|ftp) and containg port number

Tags: jquery, regex

My url will be like `localhost:5557`. And I will not allow `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://` in my url.

Also I tried

```
^(?:!(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}?$
```

But I am getting `false` when adding the `port number`.

Any suggestions please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative lookahead must be like `(?!..)` not `(?:!...)`

```
^(?!(ftp|https?):\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?::\d{4})?$
```

Comment: Can I make .com portion as optional ? Because my url may be like localhost:7678 or localhost.com:67876

Comment: `^(?!(ftp|https?):\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}|:\d{4})?$`

Comment: Hi Avinash, this is working for me. What i need now is, I need to accept www. in my regex. For ex: www.test.com, www.test.com:76676 like this. And also I am not going to accept http|https|ftp. 
Can you help me to upgrade this regex which accepts www. ?

Comment: try `^(?!(ftp|https?):\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,6})?(:\d{4})?$`, https://regex101.com/r/lD6gY2/3

Comment: But this not working for websites which may contain subdomains such as www.test.example.com
www.test.example.com:75667
^(?!(ftp|https?):\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,6})?(:\d{4})?$
Is this right for urls with sub domains ??

Comment: How to repeat this sub domain part as many times as possible ?

Comment: Please find my question below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503955/regex-for-url-without-accept-http-https-ftp-and-port-with-maximum-value