# Regex for url without accept http | https | ftp and port with maximum value

Tags: regex

1. My url does not accept http | http | ftp.
2. Url will accept www. part
3. Url which accepts any number of sub domains.
4. .com part as optional
5. Url will accept the port number maximum value 0-65535.

My regex is,

```
/^(?!(ftp|https?):\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,6})?(:\d{1,5})?$/gm
```

This regex validation goes like this,

1. www.example.com - true
2. http://example.com - false
3. www.example.etc.com - true
4. www.example.com:62444 - true
5. https://example.com - false
6. localhost:64343 - true

I am getting the error in my port part.

It will accept any 5 digit number. I need to restrict this upto 0-65535.
Because when the value exceeds 65535, It shows Uri format exception.

Any suggestions please !

Comment: No need of regex to check valid port, use comparison operators on the extracted port number. `var port = parseInt(extractedPortNo); if (port > 0 && port <= 65535) { valid port } else { invalid port }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will give you what you're looking for:

```
/^(?!(ftp|https?):\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,6})?(:\d{1,4}|:[0-6][0-5][0-5][0-3][0-5])?$/gm
```

The only thing I changed from yours was in the port analysis, from `(:\d{1,5})?` (because this will get *any* 5-digit number) to `(:\d{1,4}|:[0-6][0-5][0-5][0-3][0-5])?` (because this will instead get any **4**-digit number, and then will only get **5**-digit numbers if their digits fall within the required range).

[Click here for RegEx101 example](https://regex101.com/r/kM5oZ9/1)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But in your example why this is not accepted ? www.example.com:62444. This is within the 65535 range right ?

Comment: Check if this is valid port: `09999`, `12646`, and many like this

Comment: Hi, Trushar, If I am using the port 52889, the above regex checks only for individual digits. It check third digit within 5, if not it returns false. Any update on this ? Or Is there any regex to find the port number is less than 65535 when it is 5 digit ??